# Prevent XmlBeans from trimming whitespaces

Tags: java, xmlbeans

have a little problem with XmlBeans. It seems that it automatically is trimming the whitespaces of Strings that I am trying to add to the XML. For example. I have a list of codes and values. Each code has a value.

```
<code>
 <value/>
</code>
```

It is possible that some codes have missing values, in which case their value could be " ".

however, when I call the code objects set value method(String) than it seems like XmlBeans trims the whitespaces.

```
code.setValue(" ");
=
<code>
 <value></value>
</code>
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get around this in XmlBeans, as the correct output should be

```
<code>
 <value> </value>
</code>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ahh so this has nothing to do with how I am setting the value, but rather how I have save the file. I saved it using XmlOptions().setSavePrettyPrint(). According to the mailing list

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlbeans-user/200803.mbox/%3CAB46E23AEB035C4FBCE6F5F59D56B12701A5443B@repbex01.amer.bea.com%3E

This is what is responsible for trimming the whitespaces.